# Bug with using for in jQuery

Tags: jquery, onclick, attr

This is my code:

```
$(document).on("click", "#farm_0", function(){
  console.log($("#farm_0").attr("my_id"));
  });
$(document).on("click", "#farm_1", function(){
  console.log($("#farm_1").attr("my_id"));
  });
```

Console shows good values.
But when i try use this:

```
for(var i=0; i < 2; i++)
 {
    $(document).on("click", "#farm_"+i+"", function(){
        console.log($("#farm_"+i+"").attr("my_id"));
     });
}
```

Button's will work, but console shows just the last value or undefinded.
What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the underscore after `#farm` in:
`$(document).on("click", "#farm"+i+"", function(){`

FYI: In my opinion you shouldn't use a for loop here.

Try to add a class name to all your elements which you want to be clickable. Then add just 1 event listener for that element and use `$(this)` inside the event listener to target the clicked button. Like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".farm", function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("my_id"));
});
```

or

```
$(".farm").on("click", function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("my_id"));
});
```

Comment: ohh thanks! when i wrote this on forum i forgot this underscore, but im my code this underscore exists, but $(this) worked. thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe because of the extra `"` in `console.log($("#farm_"+i+"").attr("my_id"));`. `+""` isn't necessary.

Comment: Nice, no problem :) Please accept my answer if you think it answered your question :)